# How would I add a legend to this maptree code?

Tags: r

my code is:

```
maptree.r = function(dat, spname = "HL") {
  x = dat$x
  y = dat$y
  z = dat$z
  sp = dat$sp
  xy.interp = interp(x,y,z)

  image2D(main = "Different Sizes of Western Hemlock Trees",
          xlab = "?", 
          ylab = "?",
          xy.interp,
          col = topo.colors(12),
          sp = T)

  contour2D(xy.interp$z, 
            x = xy.interp$x, 
            y = xy.interp$y, 
            nlevels = 15, 
            col = "black", 
            add = T)

  points(x[sp == "HL" & dbh < 10], 
         y[sp == "HL" & dbh < 10], 
         xlab = "x", 
         ylab = "y", 
         col = "blue")

  points(x[sp == "HL" & dbh >= 10 & dbh < 25],
         y[sp == "HL" & dbh >= 10 & dbh < 25], 
         col = "blue", 
         cex = 2)

  points(x[sp == "HL" & dbh > 25], 
         y[sp == "HL" & dbh >= 25], 
         col = "blue", 
         cex = 3)
}

maptree.r(victoria.dat, "HL")
```

(Sorry first time posting, not sure why the code wouldn't paste on here properly)

[image: and the plot looks like (image at this link)]

I need to add a legend for what I am assuming is the different size of points and what they represent, but I am new to coding and don't know how to go about doing this or where in the code a legend should be placed.
Thanks for any help

Comment: If you gave a reproducible example I imagine someone will solve this for you.  Can you find a way to share victoria.dat or something that resembles it.

Comment: In the meantime, `legend("topleft", c("dbh < 10", "dbh 10 -  25", "dbh > 25"), pch = 1, pt.cex = 1:3, bty = "n", col = "blue")` will get you started but if you stay in base graphics you'll have to do some mucking around with margins to find somewhere on the page to put it.  Just use the legend() command after you call your function that draws the plot.

Comment: If there is a way to attach the csv file I can share it but I am not sure how to on here.